# Optimizing website text input for tablet device by pre-selecting text on edit

Tags: usability, data-entry, text-editor

Say I have a search form and a booking form: is it good usability to automatically select all text in the input if the user taps them (to edit)?

Comment: What kind of input they type? More often than not you edit a (booking) form to fix a typo, not to replace entire text with something new.

Comment: The type in all related customer data, mainly alphanumerical input

Comment: Then I'd guess they won't change from "Flowers Boulevard" to "Parking Street" but probably they may need to change from "Flowers Bolevard" to "Flowers Boulevard" (note the typo). No need to preselect all text, IMO: they will just need an extra touch to unselect and then fix.

Comment: Okay and in case of autocompleted content or numerical input like a date?

Comment: If autocompleted then probably text is already exact. If it varies then it should not be autocompleted (`autocomplete="off"` in HTML) because probably they will need to clear it each time. Dates...well, it may work in both ways but I'd prefer to be consistent (then I wouldn't do it also for dates). Note that if date is a check-in date then probably it shouldn't be pre-filled and anyway they should pick from a calendar...

Comment: Okay and say I have a special date input like this: http://www.absolut.com/us/  (see the age validation date) Would it make sense to mark the content ? I don't think so because everytime you regain focus on an input and type in, content will be overwritten anyway. So marking would suggest the user he is also able to correct a number, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should meet your users expectations.

Text inputs are one of the most familiar UI elements, so doing anything out of the ordinary, will only increase cognitive load for the user - and frustrate them if the behavior is not what they intended.

Check what the native apps do on the tablet, and mimic that. (If you are using a standard control, this should happen automatically anyway).